# Sending SMS using Windows Form application in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sms

I am developing one windows application in C# in which i want to send SMS to selected numbers.

Is there any particular trick through which i can send SMS directly through Wayztosms (or SMS sites like that)? So that it can be free to my customer.

Or if any other company exists through which i can link for SMS then please suggest me.

Comment: It's against their T&C.  `Abnormal account activity includes Sending commercial/ promotional messages or spam messages from Way2SMS`. You will probably have to find a paid for service.

Comment: @Preet Sangha: any sugetions for paid service in less amount?

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with services in India - I suggest Google really is the first port of call. Most paid services will have an API you can consume easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are lot of Paid API and free as well. But you cant assure for timely delivery in free service but in paid you ll have lot more options.

sample : http://www.mysmsmantra.com/api.html

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Try SMPP (p2p sms protocol) : it was free as i know. but these free protocols are not reliable, we are using paid protocols for our customers.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_Peer-to-Peer